# Set a child's width between parent's width and max-width

Tags: html, css

I want to build a CSS menu with some restrictions:

1. height and width of the parent `<div>` are unknown
2. the number of `<li>` is unknown
3. `<ul>` must be not smaller than `<div>` width
4. one row of `<li>` must contain as many `<li>` as possible with `max-width` of `<ul>`

What I want:

[image: what I want]

The problem is: actually `<ul>` respects initial width too much and doesn't expand. If you click 'Run the code snippet', you will see it.

HTML can be changed; flex and tricks are welcome; JS is not welcome; IE10 support is required.

```css
div {
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  background: lightblue;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 450px;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

li {
  background: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 20px 25px;
}
```

```html
<div>Stabat mater dolorosa
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: IE10 doesn't support Flexbox.. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan, `<ul>` respects initial width too much and doesn't expand. If you click 'Run the code snippet', you will see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the problem with your approach:

- The `ul` is a child of the `div`.
- The `ul` is absolutely positioned within the boundaries of the `div`, because the `div` is the nearest positioned ancestor (`position: relative`)
- As a result, the `ul` cannot extend past the width of the `div`, which is set to `inline-block`.
- So the `li` items must wrap based on the width of the `div` and the `max-width` is ignored.

I suggest you try a different method.

With pure CSS and HTML `table` elements all your requirements can be met.

```css
tr:first-child td span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background: yellow;
}

tr:last-child td {
  max-width: 450px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

li {
  background: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 20px 25px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Stabat mater dolorosa</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uhe37sqL/1/)

> 1. height and width of the parent `<div>` are unknown **NO PROBLEM**
> 2. the number of `<li>` is unknown **NO PROBLEM**
> 3. `<ul>` must be not smaller than `<div>` width **YES**
> 4. one row of `<li>` must contain as many `<li>` as possible with `max-width` of `<ul>` **YES**
> 5. No JavaScript **YES**
> 6. IE10 support **YES**

Comment: Thank you very much @Michael_B, your solution is very elegant. Good old tables never fail! Unfortunately, now I understand that there must be one more restriction... I will formulate and post a new question.