# How do I stop max-width from being ignored by positioned item?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a hover menu that requires certain elements to be positioned, but I can't get the text to expand to max-width. It just sets itself to the min-width.

I set the max-width to something really big as an example, but you can see it's just ignored under the Pages sub-menu.

It seems like if I remove position relative on the `li`, the text wraps, but that affects my menu.

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.toggle {
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#shop-navigation .sub-menu,
#shop-navigation,
#shop-navigation [type="checkbox"]:checked~.sub-menu-toggle span,
.hidden-xs-up {
  display: none;
}

#shop-navigation .menu li {
  position: relative;
}

#shop-navigation a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 4rem 0.5rem 15px;
  margin: 0 -15px;
}

#shop-navigation .menu .sub-menu-toggle {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 3rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

#shop-navigation .sub-menu a {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#shop-navigation .sub-menu ul a {
  padding-left: 45px;
}

#shop-navigation [type="checkbox"]:checked~.sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

#shop-navigation [type="checkbox"]:checked~.sub-menu-toggle:before {
  content: "-";
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #shop-navigation a {
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-right: -30px;
  }
  #shop-navigation a {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 4rem;
  }
  #shop-navigation .menu .sub-menu-toggle {
    width: 4rem;
  }
  #shop-navigation .sub-menu a {
    padding-left: 45px;
  }
  #shop-navigation .sub-menu ul a {
    padding-left: 60px;
  }
}

#shop-navigation .sub-menu-toggle,
#shop-navigation [type="checkbox"]:checked~.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

#shop-navigation {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#shop-navigation {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#shop-navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#shop-navigation {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  z-index: 2020;
}

#shop-navigation .menu {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

#shop-navigation li {
  margin: 0 0.5rem 1rem;
}

#shop-navigation a {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#shop-navigation .menu-item-has-children>a:first-child::after {
  content: " \f107";
  color: #4e9197;
}

#shop-navigation .sub-menu .menu-item-has-children>a:first-child::after {
  content: " \f105";
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#shop-navigation .sub-menu .sub-menu .menu-item-has-children>a:first-child::after {
  content: "";
}

#shop-navigation .menu-item-has-children:hover>.sub-menu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2030;
}

#shop-navigation .sub-menu {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

#shop-navigation .sub-menu .sub-menu {
  left: 100%;
  top: -1px;
  margin: -0.25rem 0 0 -0.25rem;
}

#shop-navigation .sub-menu>li:first-child>.sub-menu {
  margin-top: 0;
}

#shop-navigation .sub-menu li {
  background: #ffffff;
  min-width: 10rem;
  max-width: 200rem;
  margin: 0 0 1px;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

#shop-navigation .sub-menu a {
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0.25rem 1rem;
}

#shop-navigation .sub-menu li:first-child>a {
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
}

#shop-navigation .sub-menu li:last-child>a {
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

#shop-navigation .sub-menu .menu-item-has-children a {
  padding-right: 2.25rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<nav id="shop-navigation" class="main-navigation text-nohyphen" role="navigation">
  <ul id="shop-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-2131" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-2131 menu-item-home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1051" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1051 menu-item-depth"><a href="#">Depth</a><input id="expand-1051" class="hidden-xs-up" type="checkbox"><a class="toggle sub-menu-toggle" href="#" data-for="expand-1051" aria-label="Expand sub-menu"><span>+</span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-1052" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1052 menu-item-level-01"><a href="#">Level 01</a><input id="expand-1052" class="hidden-xs-up" type="checkbox"><a class="toggle sub-menu-toggle" href="#" data-for="expand-1052" aria-label="Expand sub-menu"><span>+</span></a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-1053" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1053 menu-item-level-02"><a href="#">Level 02</a><input id="expand-1053" class="hidden-xs-up" type="checkbox"><a class="toggle sub-menu-toggle" href="#" data-for="expand-1053" aria-label="Expand sub-menu"><span>+</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-1937" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1937 menu-item-level-01a"><a href="#">Level 01a</a><input id="expand-1937" class="hidden-xs-up" type="checkbox"><a class="toggle sub-menu-toggle" href="#" data-for="expand-1937" aria-label="Expand sub-menu"><span>+</span></a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-1938" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1938 menu-item-level-02"><a href="#">Level 02</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1940" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1940 menu-item-level-02a"><a href="#">Level 02a</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-1939" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1939 menu-item-level-01b"><a href="#">Level 01b</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-1046" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1046 menu-item-pages"><a href="#">Pages</a><input id="expand-1046" class="hidden-xs-up" type="checkbox"><a class="toggle sub-menu-toggle" href="#" data-for="expand-1046" aria-label="Expand sub-menu"><span>+</span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu" style="right: auto;">
        <li id="menu-item-1695" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1695 menu-item-page-image-alignment"><a href="#">Page Image Alignment</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1693" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1693 menu-item-page-image-alignment"><a href="#">Page Image Alignment</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1696" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1696 menu-item-page-markup-and-formatting"><a href="#">Page Markup And Formatting</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1694" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1694 menu-item-page-markup-and-formatting"><a href="#">Page Markup And Formatting</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying a `max-width` to relatively-positioned elements (the `li`s).

These elements exist inside absolutely-positioned containers (the `ul`s).

In CSS positioning, the container sets the boundaries for positioned children, not `width`, `height`, `max-width` or something else. The positioned element is confined to the boundaries of its parent.

So your `max-width: 200rem` is being overridden by the width of the container.

This post provides more details and may help further explain the problem:

- [Set a child's width between parent's width and max-width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43776945/3597276)

---

If you just want the `li` text to not wrap, add `white-space: nowrap`:

```
#shop-navigation .sub-menu li {
    background: #ffffff;
    min-width: 10rem;
    max-width: 200rem;
    margin: 0 0 1px;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    white-space: nowrap; /* NEW */
}
```

Comment: I actually want the text to wrap, just not until it reaches max-width. Is there no way around this with the same visual result?

Comment: Have you tried setting a width to the `ul`? `#shop-navigation .menu-item-has-children:hover > .sub-menu { display: block;  position: absolute;
    z-index: 2030;  width: 15em; }`

Comment: Width works. Min-width just acts like width. However this method means the menu item won't start with a minimum width and expand to max width when needed. After looking at how some other sites do it, it seems like they have fixed width also. I guess there's no way around this.